# Make this picture in the center

Tags: horizontal-alignment

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article} %
    \usepackage{pifont} %bouni  
    %-----accent                        
    \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} %écrire directement les accents et il peut poser des problème
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
      %-----
    \usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}
     \usepackage{graphicx}                    % Enable pdflatex
      \usepackage{wrapfig}
      \usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm}     % Math packages
      %%%%%%%%%%%%% dimension ancien des marges %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
      \usepackage{geometry}
      \geometry{left=2cm,right=2cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm}
      %%%%%%%%%%%%% style des sections %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
     \frenchspacing              % Better looking spacings after periods
      \usepackage{sectsty}
      \sectionfont{%                        % Change font of \section command
    \usefont{OT1}{phv}{b}{n}%       % bch-b-n: CharterBT-Bold font
     \sectionrule{0pt}{0pt}{-5pt}{1pt}}
     %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Macros %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
      \newcommand{\sepspace}{\vspace*{1em}}     % Vertical space macro
      \newcommand{\MyName}[1]{ % Name
        \Huge \usefont{OT1}{phv}{b}{n} \hfill #1
        \par \normalsize \normalfont}
      \newcommand{\MySlogan}[1]{ % Slogan}{optional)
    \large \usefont{OT1}{phv}{m}{n}\hfill \textit{#1}
    \par \normalsize \normalfont}
      %%% ------------------------------------------------------------
      \pagestyle{empty}           % No pagenumbers/headers/footers
     %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Begin Document %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
     \begin{document}
     %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Photo et title %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    %---------------------------
   \begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.5\textwidth}
   \vspace*{-2em}
   \includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{picture}
    \end{wrapfigure}
   %---------------------------
   \MyName{Name Name}
    \MySlogan{Curriculum Vitae (\today)}
    %\MySlogan{Curriculum Vitae (October 2016)}
    %---------------------------
    \sepspace  % Si on ajoute encore \sepspace on aura plus d'espace
    $$$$
     %%%%%%%%%%%%%% Personal details%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \section*{Informations personelles}

    \end{document}
```

After compilation I get

[image]

However, my goal is to obtain

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the desired output with the following amendments.

```
        \documentclass[a4paper,10pt,demo    ]{article} %
    \usepackage{pifont} %bouni  
    %-----accent                        
    \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} %écrire directement les accents et il peut poser des problème
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
      %-----
    \usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}
     \usepackage{graphicx}                    % Enable pdflatex
      \usepackage{wrapfig}
      \usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm}     % Math packages
      %%%%%%%%%%%%% dimension ancien des marges %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
      \usepackage{geometry}
      \geometry{left=2cm,right=2cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm}
      %%%%%%%%%%%%% style des sections %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
     \frenchspacing              % Better looking spacings after periods
      \usepackage{sectsty}
      \sectionfont{%                        % Change font of \section command
    \usefont{OT1}{phv}{b}{n}%       % bch-b-n: CharterBT-Bold font
     \sectionrule{0pt}{0pt}{-5pt}{1pt}}
     %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Macros %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
      \newcommand{\sepspace}{\vspace*{1em}}     % Vertical space macro
      \newcommand{\MyName}[1]{ % Name
        \Huge \usefont{OT1}{phv}{b}{n} \hfill #1
        \par \normalsize \normalfont}
      \newcommand{\MySlogan}[1]{ % Slogan}{optional)
    \large \usefont{OT1}{phv}{m}{n}\hfill \textit{#1}
    \par \normalsize \normalfont}
      %%% ------------------------------------------------------------
      \pagestyle{empty}           % No pagenumbers/headers/footers
     %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Begin Document %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
     \begin{document}
     %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Photo et title %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    %---------------------------
   \begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.5\textwidth}
   \vspace*{-2em}
   \hfill\makebox[0.075\textwidth][l]{\includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{picture}}
    \end{wrapfigure}
   %---------------------------
   \MyName{Name Name}
    \MySlogan{Curriculum Vitae \\ \null\hfill  (\today)}
    %\MySlogan{Curriculum Vitae (October 2016)}
    %---------------------------
    \sepspace  % Si on ajoute encore \sepspace on aura plus d'espace
    $$$$
     %%%%%%%%%%%%%% Personal details%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \section*{Informations personelles}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to apply to your picture, you should remove `demo` option.

Comment: Could you please add all the codes?Thanks

Comment: @Schüler
I've just attached the whole code, as you can see I made a box with the half width of the picture because I wanted to set your picture in the center.

Comment: Thank you. I post another similar question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/463659/make-the-picture-in-the-right-and-the-name-in-the-left

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution with `\begin{flushright}` command and some manual adjustment.

```
 \documentclass[a4paper,10pt,demo]{article} %
    \usepackage{pifont} %bouni  
    %-----accent                        
    \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} %écrire directement les accents et il peut poser des problème
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
      %-----
    \usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}
     \usepackage{graphicx}                    % Enable pdflatex
      \usepackage{wrapfig}
      \usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm}     % Math packages
      %%%%%%%%%%%%% dimension ancien des marges %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
      \usepackage{geometry}
      \geometry{left=2cm,right=2cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm}
      %%%%%%%%%%%%% style des sections %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
     \frenchspacing              % Better looking spacings after periods
      \usepackage{sectsty}
      \sectionfont{%                        % Change font of \section command
    \usefont{OT1}{phv}{b}{n}%       % bch-b-n: CharterBT-Bold font
     \sectionrule{0pt}{0pt}{-5pt}{1pt}}
     %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Macros %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
      \newcommand{\sepspace}{\vspace*{1em}}     % Vertical space macro
      \newcommand{\MyName}[1]{ % Name
        \Huge \usefont{OT1}{phv}{b}{n} \hfill #1
        \par \normalsize \normalfont}
      \newcommand{\MySlogan}[1]{ % Slogan}{optional)
    \large \usefont{OT1}{phv}{m}{n}\hfill \textit{#1}
    \par \normalsize \normalfont}
      %%% ------------------------------------------------------------
      \pagestyle{empty}           % No pagenumbers/headers/footers
     %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Begin Document %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
     \begin{document}
     %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Photo et title %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    %---------------------------
   \begin{wrapfigure}{l}{16cm}
   \vspace*{-16em}
   \begin{center}
   \includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{picture}
   \end{center}
    \end{wrapfigure}
   %---------------------------
   \begin{flushright}
   \MyName{Name Name}
    \MySlogan{Curriculum Vitae\\ (\today)}
    %\MySlogan{Curriculum Vitae (October 2016)}
    %---------------------------
    \sepspace  % Si on ajoute encore \sepspace on aura plus d'espace
    \end{flushright}
    $$$$
     %%%%%%%%%%%%%% Personal details%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \section*{Informations personelles}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. However after compilation my picture does not appear. I get always the black picture

Comment: Remove 'demo' option in '\documentclass'.

Comment: Thank you. I post another similar question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/463659/make-the-picture-in-the-right-and-the-name-in-the-left