# Make the picture in the right and the name in the left

Tags: horizontal-alignment

According to this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/463648/make-this-picture-in-the-center/463653#463653) we have:

```
 \documentclass[a4paper,10pt,demo]{article} %
    \usepackage{pifont} %bouni  
    %-----accent                        
    \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} %écrire directement les accents et il peut poser des problème
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
      %-----
    \usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}
     \usepackage{graphicx}                    % Enable pdflatex
      \usepackage{wrapfig}
      \usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm}     % Math packages
      %%%%%%%%%%%%% dimension ancien des marges %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
      \usepackage{geometry}
      \geometry{left=2cm,right=2cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm}
      %%%%%%%%%%%%% style des sections %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
     \frenchspacing              % Better looking spacings after periods
      \usepackage{sectsty}
      \sectionfont{%                        % Change font of \section command
    \usefont{OT1}{phv}{b}{n}%       % bch-b-n: CharterBT-Bold font
     \sectionrule{0pt}{0pt}{-5pt}{1pt}}
     %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Macros %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
      \newcommand{\sepspace}{\vspace*{1em}}     % Vertical space macro
      \newcommand{\MyName}[1]{ % Name
        \Huge \usefont{OT1}{phv}{b}{n} \hfill #1
        \par \normalsize \normalfont}
      \newcommand{\MySlogan}[1]{ % Slogan}{optional)
    \large \usefont{OT1}{phv}{m}{n}\hfill \textit{#1}
    \par \normalsize \normalfont}
      %%% ------------------------------------------------------------
      \pagestyle{empty}           % No pagenumbers/headers/footers
     %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Begin Document %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
     \begin{document}
     %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Photo et title %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    %---------------------------
   \begin{wrapfigure}{l}{16cm}
   \vspace*{-16em}
   \begin{center}
   \includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{picture}
   \end{center}
    \end{wrapfigure}
   %---------------------------
   \begin{flushright}
   \MyName{Name Name}
    \MySlogan{Curriculum Vitae\\ (\today)}
    %\MySlogan{Curriculum Vitae (October 2016)}
    %---------------------------
    \sepspace  % Si on ajoute encore \sepspace on aura plus d'espace
    \end{flushright}
    $$$$
     %%%%%%%%%%%%%% Personal details%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \section*{Informations personelles}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

However, I think it will be better if we get like this

[image]

Comment: Have you heard about the `moderncv` package? Of course, I don't want to hold you back from writing your own cv from scratch, but you could also just look at what has been invented so far and see if one of the design options pleases you.

Comment: Unfortunately no.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`wrapfigure` is the wrong tool.

Here are the two ways you mention.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{left=2cm,right=2cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm}

\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{sectsty}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm}

\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}

\frenchspacing
\sectionfont{%
  \fontfamily{phv}\bfseries
  \sectionrule{0pt}{0pt}{-5pt}{1pt}%
}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Photo et title %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{flushleft}

\hspace*{\fill}%
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
  \includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{example-image-9x16}
\end{tabular}
\hspace*{\fill}%
\makebox[0pt][r]{%
  \fontfamily{phv}\large
  \begin{tabular}{@{}r@{}}
  \Huge\bfseries Name Name \\[1ex]
  Curriculum Vitae\\ (\today)
  \end{tabular}%
}

\end{flushleft}

\section*{Informations personelles}

\bigskip

\begin{flushleft}

\makebox[0pt][l]{%
  \fontfamily{phv}\large
  \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
  \Huge\bfseries Name Name \\[1ex]
  Curriculum Vitae\\ (\today)
  \end{tabular}%
}
\hspace*{\fill}%
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
  \includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{example-image-9x16}
\end{tabular}

\end{flushleft}

\section*{Informations personelles}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Another variation:

```
\begin{flushleft}

\hspace*{\fill}%
\fontfamily{phv}\large
\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
\Huge\bfseries Name Name \\[1ex]
Curriculum Vitae\\ (\today)
\end{tabular}%
\hspace*{\fill}%
\makebox[0pt][r]{%
  \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
  \includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{example-image-9x16}
  \end{tabular}
}

\end{flushleft}
```

[image]

Comment: Dear Professor if I want `\makebox[0pt][r]{%
      \fontfamily{phv}\large
      \begin{tabular}{@{}r@{}}
      \Huge\bfseries Name Name \\[1ex]
      Curriculum Vitae\\ (\today)
      \end{tabular}%
    }` will be in the center. How can I modify the above codes? Thank you.

Comment: @Schüler I added the variation

Answer (score 3):

If I were you, I would absolutely use `tikz`.

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,10pt,demo]{article} %
    \usepackage{pifont} %bouni  
    %-----accent                        
    \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} %écrire directement les accents et il peut poser des problème
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
      %-----
    \usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}
     \usepackage{graphicx}                    % Enable pdflatex
      \usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm}     % Math packages
      \usepackage{tikz}
      %%%%%%%%%%%%% dimension ancien des marges %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
      \usepackage{geometry}
      \geometry{left=2cm,right=2cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm}
      %%%%%%%%%%%%% style des sections %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
     \frenchspacing              % Better looking spacings after periods
      \usepackage{sectsty}
      \sectionfont{%                        % Change font of \section command
    \usefont{OT1}{phv}{b}{n}%       % bch-b-n: CharterBT-Bold font
     \sectionrule{0pt}{0pt}{-5pt}{1pt}}
     %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Macros %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand\mytitle[3]{%
    \noindent\begin{tikzpicture}
        \node [align=left] (name) at (0,0) 
        {\Huge\usefont{OT1}{phv}{b}{n}#1\\
        \large\usefont{OT1}{phv}{m}{n}\textit{#2}\\(#3)};
        \node [anchor=east, xshift=-.15\textwidth] at (\textwidth, 0) {\includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{picture}};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
    }
      %%% ------------------------------------------------------------
      \pagestyle{empty}           % No pagenumbers/headers/footers
     %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Begin Document %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
     \begin{document}
\mytitle{Name Name}{Curriculum Vitae}{\today}
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%% Personal details%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section*{Informations personelles}

\end{document}
```

[image]

P.S. You can also modify your code to achieve above picture without using `tikz`.

Comment: Thank you. however your codes does not compilate even if I add \end{document}

Comment: sorry, the end was forgotten to be put!, check it now. It must work like a charm :D.

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,demo]{article} %
%%%%%%%%%%%%% dimension ancien des marges %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[hmargin=2cm, lmargin=1.5cm]{geometry}
%   \geometry{left=2cm,right=2cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm}
%-----accent
%\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} %écrire directement les accents et il peut poser des problème
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pifont} %bouni
  %-----
\usepackage[demo,
            export]{adjustbox}          % also load graphicx,
                                        % enable insert and positioning images
%\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm}    % Math packages
\usepackage{makecell}                   % Table package
%%%%%%%%%%%%% style des sections %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\frenchspacing                         % Better looking spacings after periods
\usepackage{sectsty}
\sectionfont{%                         % Change font of \section command
\usefont{OT1}{phv}{b}{n}               % bch-b-n: CharterBT-Bold font
\sectionrule{0pt}{0pt}{-5pt}{1pt}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Macros %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\sepspace}{\vspace*{1em}}     % Vertical space macro
\newcommand{\MyName}[1]{ % Name
            \fontfamily{phv}\Huge\sffamily\textbf{#1}}
\newcommand{\MySlogan}[1]{ % Slogan}{optional)
            \fontfamily{phv}\large\sffamily\slshape #1}
%%% ------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,
            linkcolor=blue,
            urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}    % had to be the last in preamble

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Begin Document %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\pagestyle{empty}           % No pagenumbers/headers/footers
\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Photo et title %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%---------------------------
\noindent\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l r}
\makecell[r]{
\MyName{Name Name}
\MySlogan{Curriculum Vitae\\ (\today)}
             }
    &   \includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth, valign=c]{picture}
\end{tabular*}
%---------------------------
\sepspace  % Si on ajoute encore \sepspace on aura plus d'espace
%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Personal details%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section*{Informations personelles}

\end{document}
```

using table for your name and image placement gives you freedom to put where you like to have. just insert it to according column: (text in the first, image in the last or vice versa). i also slightly simplified and reorganized your preamble.

edit:  the definition of `\MyName`, `\MySlogan` and table organization are changed (improved).

[image]

Comment: Thank you. However, I want to get the picture not in the center but in the extreme right.

Comment: @Schüler, sorry, i was interrupted at loading answer. now i finish it and move image on the right.  the last is with suggested code straightforward ;-)